# Uploading files to s3 using s3cmd in parallel

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, parallel-processing, s3cmd, gnu-parallel

I've got a whole heap of files on a server, and I want to upload these onto S3. The files are stored with a .data extension, but really they're just a bunch of jpegs,pngs,zips or pdfs.

I've already written a short script which finds the mime type and uploads them onto S3 and that works but it's slow. Is there any way to make the below run using gnu parallel?

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in $(find -name "*.data") 
do 
        data=".data" 
        extension=`file $n | cut -d ' ' -f2 | awk '{print tolower($0)}'` 
        mimetype=`file --mime-type $n | cut -d ' ' -f2`
        fullpath=`readlink -f $n`

        changed="${fullpath/.data/.$extension}"

        filePathWithExtensionChanged=${changed#*internal_data}

        s3upload="s3cmd put -m $mimetype --acl-public $fullpath s3://tff-xenforo-data"$filePathWithExtensionChanged     

        response=`$s3upload`
        echo $response 

done
```

Also I'm sure this code could be greatly improved in general :) Feedback tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parallel upload possible with Python and boto

Comment: Nod I could have written something in go or another language, but I was trying to do it "all in bash".. for no particular reason.

Comment: [Possible solution here](http://blog.aclarke.eu/moving-copying-lots-of-s3-files-quickly-using-gnu-parallel/)

Comment: Aye :) I read that too, but what I couldn't work out was the important part of it, which would be how I'd create the list of files to send into parallel.

Comment: Can't you redirect `find -name "*.data"` to a file and pass that file to parallel?

`find -name "*.data" > mydata.txt`
`parallel -j5 "doit {}" < mydatatxt`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are clearly skilled in writing shell, and extremely close to a solution:

```
s3upload_single() {
    n=$1
    data=".data" 
    extension=`file $n | cut -d ' ' -f2 | awk '{print tolower($0)}'` 
    mimetype=`file --mime-type $n | cut -d ' ' -f2`
    fullpath=`readlink -f $n`

    changed="${fullpath/.data/.$extension}"

    filePathWithExtensionChanged=${changed#*internal_data}

    s3upload="s3cmd put -m $mimetype --acl-public $fullpath s3://tff-xenforo-data"$filePathWithExtensionChanged     

    response=`$s3upload`
    echo $response 
}
export -f s3upload_single
find -name "*.data" | parallel s3upload_single
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you! if I'm reading this right, would this run all the files that `find - name "*.data"` returns, and run every single one in parallel? If so that's really cool, but I'm assuming it would fall over if `find -name "*.data"` returned say uhh 80k files

Comment: Almost: `parallel` defaults to one process per cpu core. If you want to run as many as possible use `parallel -j0`. This will still not run 80k in parallel, but stop spawning more when there are no more file handles or processes left.

Comment: You can also use xargs for this. Just change the last line to `find -name '*.data" | xargs -n 1 -P 10 s3upload_single`. See this link: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/05/01/an-easy-way-to-run-many-tasks-in-parallel/

Answer (score 3):

you can just use [s3cmd-modified](https://github.com/pcorliss/s3cmd-modification) which allows you to put/get/sync with multiple workers in parallel

`$ git clone https://github.com/pcorliss/s3cmd-modification.git
    $ cd s3cmd-modification
    $ python setup.py install
    $ s3cmd --parallel --workers=4 sync /source/path s3://target/path`

Comment: This project is 9 years old as of last commit :/

Answer (score -1):

Use aws cli. It supports parallel upload of files and it is really fast while uploading and downloading.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: The word 'parallel' does not appear in the docs. How is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Try [s3-cli](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-cli): 
Command line utility frontend to node-s3-client. Inspired by s3cmd and attempts to be a drop-in replacement.

Paraphrasing from https://erikzaadi.com/2015/04/27/s3cmd-is-dead-long-live-s3-cli/ :

> This is a inplace replace to s3cmd, written in node (yaay!), which works flawlessly with the existing s3cmd configuration, which (amongs other awsome stuff), uploads to S3 in parallel, saving LOADS of time.
>
> ```
> -        system "s3cmd sync --delete-removed . s3://yourbucket.com/"
> +        system "s3-cli sync --delete-removed . s3://yourbucket.com/"
> ```